# imploding an array to echo a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to print the values from an array as a string.  I got this code from the PHP documents, but I'm getting a string conversion error.  The values are numbers and I can see them

```
$viz_array_qry = "SELECT (`column_name`) FROM table_name WHERE option_name='$option_name'";
$result = mysql_query($viz_array_qry);
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
    $viz_array = implode (',',$result_array);
}
    print_r($viz_array);

    //echo $viz_array;  <!-- no result-->
```

If I var_dump the $result_array I get the list of the values below.  But I just want to display them as

```
0,0,57,39,40
```

I cant work out why the implode it not working?

```
 array (size=5)
 0 => 
   array (size=1)
     'column_name' => string '0' (length=1)
 1 => 
   array (size=1)
     'column_name' => string '0' (length=1)
 2 => 
   array (size=1)
     'column_name' => string '57' (length=2)
 3 => 
   array (size=1)
     'column_name' => string '39' (length=2)
 4 => 
   array (size=1)
     'column_name' => string '40' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only store value of column_name (`$row['column_name']`) instead of `$row` (which is an array) and move `implode` outside of loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['column_name'];
}

echo implode(',', $result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode after the While loop:

```
$viz_array_qry = "SELECT (`column_name`) FROM table_name WHERE option_name='$option_name'";
$result = mysql_query($viz_array_qry);
$result_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $result_array[] = $row;
}

$viz_array = implode (',',$result_array);
print_r($viz_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not want to change the existing code and store the data in the array as you are doing you can use array_map() to get the result as you want as below

```
$arr = array(0=>array('column_name'=>'0'),1=>array('column_name'=>'0'),
3=>array('column_name'=>'57'),4=>array('column_name'=>'39'));

function get_col($col) {
    return $col["column_name"];
}

$values = implode(array_map("get_col", $arr), ',');

echo $values ;
```

Comment: Isn't that a workaround on a wrong implementation on his side? I think that adding 2 lines (an array that holds the IDs and the final `implode` the array) is easier and more understandable than your solution.

Comment: Yes thats the reason I mentioned "Even if you do not want to change the existing code" if at all the array needs to be used for some other purpose.

Comment: Ok, well I don't need that this time, but thanks for the info Abhik Chakraborty.